# ATL templates for IDispatch derived classes

Tags: c++, com, atl

Tomorrow I have planed to do some IDispatch related work, and I will have to create a class that supports this interface.

I have been using ATL classes for a while to create COM objects and manage COM pointers, so I would like to use them for my class as well. But research so far, and discussions with colleagues have led me to believe that I need all the heavyweight IDL stuff even if I want to create a simple class with one property or method.

If that's the case I'll probably resort to writing everything from scratch, but I still hope I'm missing something. Is there a template I've missed?

Comment: There's [IDispatchImpl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/494h01te.aspx). I don't know how much it helps, though.

Comment: It needs those IIDs and LIBIDs, which I don't need or want for the task. But thanks.

Comment: You always need to use an `IID` for every interface, but you do not have to specify a `LIBID` if you do not need it.  `IDispatchImpl` will use a default internally.

Comment: What if you're just passing IDispatch to another server for callback purposes? It would take pointer, call get IDs of names, or just plainly call method0 for example?

Comment: Example: http://www.ookii.org/post/using_ixmlhttprequestonreadystatechange_from_c.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATL has an `IDispatchImpl` class.

Comment: +1, but this class uses the typelib. The OP will likely object to that, but IMO just using IDL from the very beginning and embedding the typelib makes life easier.

Comment: `IDispatchImpl`'s default behavior is to use a TypeLib, but it does not access the TypeLib directly.  You can use the `tihclass` parameter to provide a dummy class that bypasses that behavior.  Otherwise, just derive from `IDispatch` directly and implement its methods manually.  Many of them can just return `E_NOTIMPL`.